# What is FrontController design pattern? How much level is DispatcherServlet using it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns, front-controller

Actually I am trying to understand the DispatcherServlet and came to know that it is following the FrontController Design Pattern.
While trying to understand the FrontController design pattern came across this link
[FrontController from Oracle Doc reference](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html)
Not much understood as I am beginner, but few things I understood Like Below

If we don't have FrontController we often try to duplicate the code in multiple controller like authentication and Authorization. And because of which maintainability becomes a big issue if we want to change something in future. So having frontController in place we can move the basic functionality to frontController and changes can be done easily.

When I explained Same thing in the interview he asked me what are those basic functionalities. I told Internalization, viewResolver, Authentication, Authorization etc. And now again asked consider like there is no dispatcher Servlet how do you handle those functionalities in each controller?

Since am basically a Desktop Application developer I couldn't answer for his next question.

So here are my questions

1. Firstly, is my understanding correct?
2. If my understand is correct, how to answer for the second question of the Interviewer? Which is consider like if there is no dispatcher Servlet how do you handle those functionalities in each controller? means asked me to write some pseudo code of the common functionalities. Which I couldn't as I am swing developer. Could someone please explain me, with some sample code which we repeat across the controller and now with dispatcher we could avoid.
3. If we Start comparing DispatcherServlet with frontController Design Pattern can we say like LocaleResolver, HandlerMapping, ThemeResolver, ViewResolver, HandlerExceptionResolver, HandlerAdapter, MultipartResolver etc. are Helper classes for DispatcherServlet?

Answer (score 1):

The front controller design pattern means that all requests that come for a resource in an application will be handled by a single handler and then dispatched to the appropriate handler for that type of request. The front controller may use other helpers to achieve the dispatching mechanism.

Front Controller design pattern could be implemented by either of following two ways.

1. **Using Servlet**
2. **Using Filter**

Spring Framework implemented FrontController Design Patter using DispatcherServlet for intercepting each request and delegate to responsible controller to process the request.

If interviewer asks you, what happened if you don't have DispatcherServlet then how you manage all these authentication and authorization things, you can simply say that I can define a Filter which will intercept each request. Filter should be responsible for dispatching,authentication and authorization thing. Struts uses Filter to implement FrontController Design pattern.

Comment: Do you agree to the fact that dispatcherServlet handles any common functionality which would have been scattered throughout all the contollers?if so what are they in your opinion?

Comment: Do you think that dispatcherServlet handles authentication and authorization mechanism ?

Comment: No Spring have Spring Security module which actually uses filter chain for manage authentication and authorization. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Ok what do you think of my first comment forget about security for now.

Comment: Yes having frontcontroller helps you to have a central place where each and every request comes first. By this you can put all the common logic over there without duplicating them into each component and also helps in maintenance because we have to change in one place only.

Comment: i have understood that after reading regarding frontController. My question is same as mentioned in first Comment. Is DispatcherServlet also following that? please read my first comment again. i need answer for that.

Comment: Sorry I left to read that part, you should not say that DispatcherServlet manages Authentication & Authorization part. It only delegates things to other component like Handler,View Resolve etc. http://www.waitingforcode.com/spring-framework/spring-dispatcherservlet-lifecycle/read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180049/discussion-between-java-and-gaurav-srivastav).

Comment: Just curious, Isn't delegation a kind of managing the things?

Answer (score 0):

(1) [FrontController](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) is simply the central place where all the external requests are received by and pass each of those requests to the appropriate handler. As you have explained since this is the central place for all the requests, it can be used to perform all the common things like security, logging etc.

(2) **DispatcherServlet** is the actually the front controller of Spring MVC. It intercepts each request and then **dispatches** each to the appropriate controller which has been registered in Spring Application Context.

> consider like if there is no dispatcher Servlet how do you handle
>   those functionalities in each controller ?

For this one, I don't think this question implies that you need to write same code in each controller. (If it does, it cannot be a good idea)

You can do something like implementing a separate service which would do those common things (cross cutting concerns) for you can orchestrate all in coming requests.

Comment: You have mentioned that front controller can handle all the common functionality. But didn't mentioned anywhere that dispatcherServlet is also following it.like it also helping us from not duplicating the some functionalities across the controllers. Please explain that is dispatcherServlet only used to redirect ?

Comment: Is internalization is such one common functionality that dispatcherServlet acting as front controller design pattern handled out in single place.? If dispatcherServlet is not there how would have been handled across all controller ?will internalization logic would have end up in duplication?

Answer (score 0):

### Front Controller Definition

> The front controller is responsible for handling all the requests for
>   a website. For web application developers, it can be a very useful
>   structure, as it allows the developers the flexibility and the ability
>   to reuse the code without having to add again and again.It provides a single point of action to handle the all coming requests to the J2EE web application, it forwards the request to specific application controller to access model and view for presentation
>   tier resources.

---

lets check the functionality of the Dispatcher Servlet to see if it is exactly the front end: 
Consider the diagram below taken from https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch15s02.html:

[image]

As you can see in the preceding diagram, the front controller is introduced for the
MVC pattern. It is implemented as a `javax.servlet.Servlet` servlet such as ActionServlet in struts, FacesServlet in JSF, and `DispatcherServlet` in Spring MVC. It handles the incoming requests, and delegates the requests to the
specific application controller. That application controller creates and updates the model, and delegates it to the front controller for rendering. Finally, the **Front Controller** determines the specific view, and renders that model data.

**Now Consider the step as:**

1. A user clicks on the browser or submits a web form of the application. The
   request leaves the browser, either with some additional information or with
   common information. This request lands at Spring's `DispatcherServlet`, which is a
   simple servlet class as other java-based web applications. It is a Front
   Controller of the Spring MVC framework, and funnels all the incoming requests
   through the single point. The Spring MVC framework centralizes the request
   flow control by using this Front Controller.
2. A user clicks on the browser or submits a web form of the application. The
   request leaves the browser, either with some additional information or with
   common information. This request lands at Spring's `DispatcherServlet`, which is a
   simple servlet class as other java-based web applications. It is a Front
   Controller of the Spring MVC framework, and funnels all the incoming requests
   through the single point. The Spring MVC framework centralizes the request
   flow control by using this Front Controller.
3. Once a particular application controller is decided by Spring's `DispatcherServlet`
   with the help of the handler mapping configuration, `DispatcherServlet` dispatches
   that request to the selected controller. This is the actual controller responsiblefor processing information according to the user's request and its parameters.
4. Once a particular application controller is decided by Spring's `DispatcherServlet`
   with the help of the handler mapping configuration, `DispatcherServlet` dispatches
   that request to the selected controller. This is the actual controller responsiblefor processing information according to the user's request and its parameters.
5. Once a particular application controller is decided by Spring's `DispatcherServlet`
   with the help of the handler mapping configuration, `DispatcherServlet` dispatches
   that request to the selected controller. This is the actual controller responsiblefor processing information according to the user's request and its parameters.
6. Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet` renders the model to the view, and generates a
   user-readable format of the model's information
7. Finally, that information creates a response, and returns it to the user's browser
   by `DispatcherServlet`.

So The Spring MVC module provides out-of-the-box front controller pattern implementation by introducing the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` class. This is a simple servlet class, and the backbone of the Spring MVC framework. And this Servlet is integrated with the Spring IoC container to benefit the Spring's dependency pattern. Spring's web framework uses Spring for its own configuration, and all controllers are Spring beans. you can see the spring doc https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch15s02.html that admitted the usage of front controller design pattern in `DispatcherServlet`

---

## Answers specifically to your questions:

1. yes your understanding is okay but for a better view refer to my description
2. when there is no DispatcherServlet you need to define something to take care of the functionality you need and the best thing is to write a filter including your logic of authentication and authorization
3. These are not refer as **Helper classes** as it has it's own definition in OOP, you can consider them components playing part in front controller design pattern implemented version of Spring

---

## More Info:

- Majority of the definition comes from the book **Spring 5 Design Patterns** by Dinesh Rajput, you can refer this book for more info

Comment: Thanks for your effort and answer!! i even read and know all the things you mentioned in your answer after going through spring doc.what is not clear is mentioned in my question clearly. precisely i posted  3 questions in my question. please answer those.

Comment: sure, i updated my answer , an include the specific answers to your question at the end of my post